# Share access programmatically Dynamics CRM web api

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

Is there an action to programmatically share (GrantAccess) a phonecall activity to other user (systemuser) through Dynamics CRM **web api (v8.1)**? As far as seen only samples is through organization services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GrantAccess message will be available in [v9.0](https://rajeevpentyala.com/2017/10/07/whats-new-for-developersadminsend-users-dynamics-365-v-9-0/) web api.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt628816.aspx) declared this as limitation as of v8.2 webapi.

> Missing functions and actions for some organization service messages
>
> The following table lists the messages that don't have a corresponding
>   function or action after December 2016 update for Microsoft Dynamics
>   365 (online) and December 2016 Service Pack for Microsoft Dynamics 365
>   (on-premises) are applied.
>
> - GrantAccessRequest

Comment: not even thinking about v8.1... forst drawback of 8.1 vs 8.2 was sava with data returned(in version 8.1 get only guids and then create new request for neccessary fields)... Web  api got another -1point against Organization services, until some major update.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK actions available in v8.1 through WebApi. So obvious alternative solution - create action that will accept parameters phonecall reference and user and share record. And you can call that action using WebApi and JS.
Good luck.

Comment: Yes, custom action can be triggered from v8.0 webapi itself: https://debajmecrm.com/2016/01/06/dynamics-crm-web-api-action-execute/

Comment: Good point, but for my  case, made a decision -  plugin will handle the GrantAccess functionality, maybe next project with web api will add needed custom Actions