# How to grant read-write access request to a specific record of an entity to an user in Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

In **Dynamics-365** crm, I want to grant read-write access request to an user of D-365 to a specific record of an entity if the user is not privileged with that privileges.

I did that by assigning some sort of security roles to that user. But I can't do that by modifying security role.

So how can I do that without assigning security role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same **share** functionality in code using `GrantAccessRequest`, refer my [another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51856577/7920473) for C# plugin example.

For web api, your org has to be greater than v9.0 as `GrantAccess` message was [not available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47035986/7920473) in web api till v8.2

Still to achieve this object based security model, you should give users privilege to read-write that entity records through role based security model. Without user having entity edit privilege in security role they cannot edit by getting record sharing.

[Read more: Use record-based security to control access to records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/security-dev/use-record-based-security-control-access-records)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to change/update your security Roles, then you can do so by sharing a particular Record with Either Team or User.Below 2 images will help you explain how to share a Record.
Now this process below is manual and you could achieve this process programmatically as well using C# i.e server side coding

[image]

[image]

Note:
If this solves your problem do mark this answer as solved.

Comment: Just for confirmation. If I want to achieve that by server side coding(plugin or through web api calling), should i use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.grantaccessrequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9) ?

Comment: Exactly and if you google you will find some more example code as well.